# Got an error while Laravel Project Transfer in another folder

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-8

I copy my Laravel project from one folder to another folder. I tried to run `php artisan migrate`, but I got an error. No any command can be executed successfully in the new root folder. I tried to run `composer update & composer install` but it also does not work.

The error is:
`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_name.table_name' doesn't exist (SQL: select column from table_name )`

I changed the database name from `.env`. The problem is solved if the database is imported from the old database.

Comment: Try `composer --no-plugins update --no-scripts && composer --no-plugins install --no-scripts` to see if it can recover something. Also `composer -vvv ...` can shed more light where the actual error is caused. This is probably more a problem with Laravel than Composer.

Comment: Maybe you are querying from a database in any provider which causes the error

Comment: Everything is fine if I transfer the website to the next folder and create a database and run migrate cmd or any cmd it shows an error.